# While Loop to execute Airflow operator without creating many tasks

Tags: python, airflow

Requirement: Run SQL query for each date using while loop. I just wanted to iterate a task from a start date till the end date. For example: there is partition table schema.xyz_20200901. First I wanted to run task to select this partition table and update schema.table_20200901 then in next iteration it will select schema.xyz_20200902 and update schema.table_20200902 and so on.

Issue: I don't want to have a task for each partition date, how can I have only one task doing this?

[image]

```
while p< (len(BQ_result)):
BigQueryOperator(
        task_id= o_task_id + str (BQ_result['fulldate'][p]),
        bql=sql_torun.replace("_DATEPARTITION_", str (BQ_result['fulldate'][p])),
        destination_dataset_table=DESTINATION_TABLE_STG.format(
        bigQ_dataset = dest_dataset_stg,
        bigQ_table_destination = dest_table_stg,
        ),
        create_disposition=create_disposition,
        write_disposition=write_disposition,
        allow_large_results=True,
        bigquery_conn_id=bq_connection.get('connection_id'),
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        pool = BigQueryOperator_pool,
        dag=dag,
        task_concurrency=1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case should be solved by creating [dynamic operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-create-dags-dynamically). But ideally I would suggest you to use operators like [python operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html?highlight=python#module-airflow.operators.python_operator), which provides more flexibility and control over the flow.